Are there more different ways Motorola 68000 A-line and F-line traps were used than the Classic Mac way and the Lisa way?
On the Motorola 680x0 there are instruction opcodes beginning with an $A nybble or an $F nybble which are not implemented but can be trapped. Some platforms took advantage of these in their programming architecture.
On 68000 a normal instruction is 16 bits.
On Classic m68k Mac they used a series of 16-bit pseudo-instructions starting with $A and the other 12 bits specified which Toolbox function to call.
On the Apple Lisa they used I think 4 32-bit pseudo-instructions starting with $A and I think the low nybble specified the instruction, such as IUJSR, with the remaining 24 bits looking like an address (but I think they're actually not quite that). (IU stands for "intrinsic unit", kinda like a segment.)
So the Mac case is simple since the pseudo-instructions are the same length as a real instruction but in the Lisa case the trap handler will have to increment the program counter to skip both words.
I was an Amiga guy in those days and the Amiga didn't use A-line or F-line traps at all. I believe neither the Mac nor the Lisa used F-line traps either. I don't think the Atari ST used them either.
But I know nothing of other platforms, such as the various Unices running on Mac, Atari, Amiga, Sun; the Sinclair QL; the Sharp 680x0; Palm Pilot; CP/M; NeXT etc etc... and then there were the various game consoles like the Sega Genesis/Megadrive and arcade platforms like the Neo Geo...
Did most platforms that used them do it like the Mac, or was there a wide range of other ways in addition to those I'm aware of.
And did any platforms also use the F-line traps? I believe Motorola reserved them, but maybe not from the very beginning, and game platforms wouldn't be too concerned with compatibility with future CPU variants.

Aren't the F-line traps intended to be used to emulate a floating-point coprocessor if none is present? I'll bet they were used as intended by a few systems.

@Tommy Off the top of my head I think the FP opcodes were in that space and that's why Motorola reserved the space in the 68000. I think the 68881 came out with the 68020 and the $Fnnn space wasn't used until then. Stands to reason that those were trappable specifically to be able to emulate FP operations. Lisa came out in '83 and Mac and 68881 came out in '84. Unixes probably supported 68881 as soon as it came out and I can see them implementing FP emulation. I seem to remember looking at that code for 68000 Linux back in the '90s and not understanding any of it (-:

It looks like the NXP ColdFire CPUs actually had instructions in the A-line, such as mac.w

The Atari ST of course uses the Line-A traps - all of its graphic primitives are invoked by them.

@tofro I stand corrected! I knew it used TRAP but didn't know it used A-line as well. Thanks.

@tofro yes, except, not all $Fxxx opcodes are used by FPU instructions (at least not early on), so using unassigned ones is still possible - and has been done.

Is there a reason system implementers would prefer to use A- and F-line instructions over a TRAP instruction?

@jeremy I think code size. Line A/F instructions are just one 16-bit word, 12 bits of which is the operand whereas I thik TRAP has only 4 bits for the operand. So you need more instructions separate instructions beforehand to pass a trap operation number if you want more than 16.

Ah yes.  Raffzahn's answer suggests this in relation to BSR/JSR, but similar reasoning applies to TRAP.

Atari ST
Atari used Line A (Interrupt $0A) for graphics primitives. There were 15 (later 16) instructions, encoded as $A000..$A00F:



Opcode
Function




$A000
Initialize Line-A usage


$A001
Put Pixel


$A002
Get Pixel


$A003
Line


$A004
Horizontal Line


$A005
Rectangle Fill


$A006
Polygon Fill


$A007
BitBlt


$A008
TextBlt


$A009
Show Mouse


$A00A
Hide Mouse


$A00B
Transform Mouse


$A00C
Undraw Sprite


$A00D
Draw Sprite


$A00E
Copy Raster Form


$A00F
Seedfill (Not in first (RAM) TOS)



Line-F (Interrupt $0B) were used by GEM (AES?) in early TOS versions, up to and including 1.04 for internal calls. This was mainly a measure to save enough space to finally squeeze TOS into 192 KiB of ROM. A Line-F instruction is 2 bytes and provides 4096 possible functions (entry points), so replacing 4 or 6 byte BSR/JSR calls with $Fxxx does create notable savings. With TOS 1.06, introduced with the STE models in 1989, usage was dropped.
In addition TRAP instructions (Interrupt $20..$2F) were used for OS calls.



Trap No.
Function




TRAP 1
GEMDOS


TRAP 2
GEM-AES/VDI


TRAP 13
BIOS


TRAP 14
XBIOS



With a basic ST all other TRAP will throw the well known number of bombs. Later several add-on (like NVDI *1) used some as entry points, others were hooked by user software like CUBASE.
Sinclair QL
The QL did not use Line-A and Line-F only for user side FPU emulation. Only some TRAP instructions are used for OS purpose.



Trap No.
Function




TRAP #0
Supervisor Mode


TRAP #1
Hardware and Resource Management


TRAP #2
Input/ Output Management allocating resources


TRAP #3
Input/ Output Management not allocate resources


TRAP #4
SuperBASIC Interpreter



Sharp X68000
Sharp's X68000 makes extensive use of Line A, Line F and TRAPs.

Line A is used for SX-Window, its GUI
Line F provides, in addition to FPU (emulation) all (D)OS functions, encoded in the $FFxx range
TRAPs are used for some basic hardware hooks as well as hooking device drivers

Apple Macintosh
The original Mac (Old World ROM) uses Line A as entry for its toolbox and OS calls. While the original 64 KiB ROM maintained a single table, starting with the 128 KiB ROMs (Mac Plus/Mac 512Ke) two tables, one for Toolbox, one for OS calls.
An interesting side note may be that bits 8..11 (lower nibble of high byte) are used to mark various function groups or to select variants. For example bit 11 ($0800) distinguishes between both tables. Or if bit 10 is set with file system calls, execution will be asynchronous, otehr synchronous.
Consoles
Consoles - at least at that time - usually never had a resident OS and their cartridge ROMs starting at memory start ($000000), thus also no way for an OS to catch those vectors and use them for service offering.
SEGA Mega Drive (Genesis)
Like before the ROM(s) starts at $000000, so the game controls what's there. But it gets rather complicated when the CD is added, as now two 68k at different speed are present, with the second (the one that came with the CD drive) can stop the console CPU and access it's memory. In addition, the Drive CPU has a ROM at $000000, so there are services.
NGK Neo Geo
AFAIK quite similar to the mega drive - plus even more complex :))
CP/M, Unix, etc.
Not sure, but it would be rather unusual for a hardware independent OS to use any of those vectors. That is except for TRAP, as those are intended for OS use.
In case of CP/M TRAP #2 is used for BDOS calls, while TRAP #3 does the same for BIOS calls (*2).

*1 - One I remember well was Trap#4 hooked by the MS-DOS add on SuperCharger.
*2 - Although no application program should use TRAP #3 directly. To execute BIOS calls, BDOS offers function 50 to enhance upward compatibility and portability.

You might want to mention that arguments to the Atari ST line A primitives are being handed over in registers (mainly address registers pointing to parameter blocks).

@tofro yeah, sure. But the question simply about usage across many platforms, so the list itself may already be way too much (and that's me saying as the Atari-fan I am).  Also, I would think that instructions having their parameters in registers is about the most basic way instructions work, isn't it?

A small correction to the Sinclair QL: No, not all OS functions are invoked via traps. QDOS implements two additional (i.e. non-CPU) vector tables that give access to somewhat"higher-level" OS Toolbox calls.

@tofro Yes. True. I'd consider them out of scope for this. I see your point. Let me rephrase that. Better now?

@tofro Calling conventions are definitely interesting but I intentionally left them out of this question to not make the scope too broad. I do think I read somewhere using them with arguments passed on the stack though.

I suppose you meant "...to finally squeeze TOS into 192 KiB of ROM"?

Apparently neither are used in the Neo Geo

@jcaron Oops, yes.

@hippietrail Well, as a nice designer of a system, you really don't need to use (and thus, occupy) all possible features of the CPU. You can leave some of them for the application programmer to play with. And the Line-A and -F trap system can be really useful for application programs as well.

But apparently there are a couple of Megadrive/Genesis games that use A-line traps. I can confirm their existence in Star Cruiser and read that they existed in Twinkle Tale but can't find any there.

@hippietrail yes, GAMES could (and did) use it. Why should they ignore this helpful resource. And they could as the basic system did not use it.

They're not A-line or F-line instructions, but OS/9 for 68K used TRAP instructions with a word-sized selector following the instruction. This interferes with disassembly of OS/9 68K code by disassemblers that can't be told about this pattern.

Interesting! That makes it similar to how Apple Lisa A-line traps work. I'm looking at this stuff in Ghidra at the moment.
